# Unable to initialize array inside struct with ifdef'd macro

Tags: c, struct, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to initialize a struct below, known as `arduino_lcd_t`. Because the peripheral I am using can either have data written to it four bits at a time, or eight bits at a time, I decided to have a macro that would define itself accordingly. However, I cannot compile this code, probably becuase of the `#ifdef`'s macro. I get the warning

```
declaration does not declare anything
```

Is there just something I'm not doing right, or can this not be done? The relevant code is below.

```
#define FOUR_BIT_MODE 1

#ifdef FOUR_BIT_MODE
#define DATA_LEN 4;
#else
#define DATA_LEN 8
#endif

typedef struct
{
    long lighting_pin;
    long register_select_pin;
    long read_write_pin;
    long enable_pin;
    **long data_pins[DATA_LEN];**
} arduino_lcd_t;
```

Comment: `#define DATA_LEN 4;` <<--- you have `;` which goes into middle of array declaration: data_pins[4;];

Answer (score 1):

```
long data_pins[DATA_LEN];
```

When the macro will be extended it will become

```
long data_pins[4;];
```

`4;` cannot be an indice of array. Remove the `;` at the end of your macro

Comment: Thank you, I must have left the semicolon in be accident